# form layout with CSS

Tags: css, forms

I need to create a form with, half linear view (textboxes and dropdownlists in separate line) and the other half, non linear view i.e. the textboxes will appear next to each other, like first name and last name will be next to each other.

I am aware how to acomplish the linear view with CSS. I am using

```
fieldset {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 100%;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
  border-style: solid none none none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

label 
{
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
    text-align:right;
}
```

How can I get the non-linear view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you also float:left, set a width and display:inline the other input fields, the should appear on the same line

Comment: The above CSS I am using for the linear view, which is first half of the form, so, can I ignore the float:left and just use display: inline?

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline` puts the item on the same line.

`display: block` gives the item an entire line of its own.

`float: left` floats the item to the left.